# Spark dataframe json column value

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hive

I have a Dataframe in  Scala with columns value, country, process.
I want to make another Dataframe where value column should be converted to json schema format as it is a json string and other two values should remain same, i.e, in string format.

Tried with storing the data in a temporary hive table and then read it using spark.read.json so that I will get Value column in json format. Here I faced one issue like I was not able to fetch other two values (ie, country and process). So I left this approach.

Then I tried with to_json method in Dataframe but printschema is still displaying value as String column not in json format.

I need something like below.

```
root
|-- testdata1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- dat2: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
Country -> String column, not part of json data
process -> String column, not part of json data
```

Can someone suggest a best approach.

Comment: Have you considered json serialization using a library such as `circe`? You can convert to json `String` and back to the `case class` format using the library methods.

Comment: Could you please add an example for your input data and the expected output?